# Refresh token has shorter lifetime than access token

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I am using an API which uses OAuth2 for authentication. I didn't develop it so I have no ability to modify settings. When I log in, I receive the following fields:

```
access_token: abcdef
expires_in: 10000
refresh_token: fedcba
refresh_expires_in: 1000
```

It doesn't make any sense to me. Why does access token have longer lifetime than refresh token? Shouldn't it be the other way? Do you think that this is the error in their configuration or is this done on purpose? If so, what is the benefit of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO who ever set up the server was confused about the difference between an access token and a refresh token.   An access token should not have a longer life span then the refresh token.  Yes it should be the other way around.

I can see no reason to do this other than them not wanting you to ever use the refresh token.

If possible you may want to try and contact them they may not be aware of this.  At the very lease they may tell you their reasoning behind it.